# React Native. "Can't find variable" error with react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I'm implementing the downloading PDF file with **react-native-fetch-blob**. But I have an error "*Can't find variable: received*"

```
onPDFPressed(){        
    RNFetchBlob
        .config({
            notification: true,
            path: 'downloads/pdf_test.pdf',
            indicator: true,
            overwrite: true,
            addAndroidDownloads: {
                path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir +'/downloads/pdf_test.pdf',
                useDownloadManager: true,
                notification: true,
                overwrite: true,
                description: 'downloading content...',
                mime: 'application/pdf',
                mediaScannable: false
            }
        })
        .fetch('GET', 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf')
        .progress(received, total)
    {
        console.log('progress', received / total)
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `progress` function needs to get a function, not two variables as parameters. This is what you need to change to:

```
onPDFPressed(){        
    RNFetchBlob
        .config({
            notification: true,
            path: 'downloads/pdf_test.pdf',
            indicator: true,
            overwrite: true,
            addAndroidDownloads: {
                path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir +'/downloads/pdf_test.pdf',
                useDownloadManager: true,
                notification: true,
                overwrite: true,
                description: 'downloading content...',
                mime: 'application/pdf',
                mediaScannable: false
            }
        })
        .fetch('GET', 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf')
        .progress((received, total) => {
            console.log('progress', received / total)    
        })
}
```

Comment: That means the file cannot be downloaded. Did you update all the needed permissions? has the app access to the path you want to download it in? is the url reachable from the app location (you can try opening it on the simulator)?

Comment: But the .pdf file has been downloaded successfully.

Comment: Then it may be cached and therefore not really downloaded. Or maybe the file is to small and it gets downloaded in less than 250ms in which case there's not enough time to count the progress. Try with a larger file, for example: http://www.iso.org/iso/annual_report_2009.pdf

Comment: I've tried your pdf and this large file http://pepa.holla.cz/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Learning-React-Native.pdf and files has been downloaded successfully. I've checked it with Android Device Monitor. But I still don't see the logs about progress in console...